# How to exclude non-browsable members in a sandcastle xml documentation build

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sandcastle

I'd like to be able to exclude members that, although Public, are decorated with EditorBrowable.Never.

I can't see any where to do it in the options. Is there a plug-in out there where you can specify attributes to exclude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach the <exclude /> Tag to the member.